# url with # - how to import data from html table in R

Tags: r

```
url1 <- "http://www.nationmaster.com/country-info/stats/Economy/Inequality/GINI-index#1994"
url2 <- "http://www.nationmaster.com/country-info/stats/Economy/Inequality/GINI-index#1986"

tables1 <- readHTMLTable(url1)
tables2 <- readHTMLTable(url1)

View(tables1[1])
View(tables2[1])
```

The results are as for url without #1986 or #1994.

In other words: I would like to read all data from column HISTORY

Comment: url1 <- "http://www.nationmaster.com/country-info/stats/Economy/Inequality/GINI-index#1994"
url2 <- "http://www.nationmaster.com/country-info/stats/Economy/Inequality/GINI-index#1986"

tables1 <- readHTMLTable(url1)
tables2 <- readHTMLTable(url2)

View(tables1[1])
View(tables2[2])

Comment: Small mistakes corrected. But it does nit still work:

Comment: url1 <- "http://www.nationmaster.com/country-info/stats/Economy/Inequality/GINI-index#1994"
url2 <- "http://www.nationmaster.com/country-info/stats/Economy/Inequality/GINI-index#1986"

tabs <- getURL(url1)
tabs3 <- readHTMLTable(tabs, stringsAsFactors = F)

tables1 <- readHTMLTable(url1)
tables2 <- readHTMLTable(url2)

View(tables1[1])
View(tables2[1])